Artifactory overwriting last sources.jar instead of creating new one on publish from Java Gradle project
I have a Java Gradle project. This project is build by Jenkins and I try to publish the sources.jar along the library's .jar file. The Project is build by Jenkins and in the Jenkins log I can see, that he's pushing the jar file to the Artifactory server:
[pool-1-thread-3] Deploying artifact: http://*****/fw-stringutil/main-SNAPSHOT/fw-stringutil-main-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar

When I look on the Artifactory server, I cannot find the sources for the last pushed jar file. But instead I can see that the sources.jar file's timestamp from the before last push changed. It looks to me that artifactory is pushing the sources.jar file to the before built timecode. Is this a bug or do I miss something?
Artifactory native UI of the library
Here some Version Info:
Artifactory: Artifactory OSS Open source license 7.90.14 rev
Gradle: 8.9
Gradle Artifactory Plugin: 5.2.3
Jenkins: 2.462.3
Java: 17.0.6 (Azul Systems)
Kind regards,
sasa
I already tried updating artifactory the newest version(7.90.14). I saw the same problem with: 7.84.17

Try to clear artifactory cache.. In Artifactory, navigate to the cached file, and manually trigger a "delete and re-upload" of the latest sources.jar. You can also try invalidating the cache for that repository.

We are using Artifactory OSS. Where can I invalidate the cache?

Via UI or via API. You'll need to navigate to admin --> repor --> cache or     curl -u : -X DELETE "http:///artifactory/api/storage/?deleteCache=true"
